# Paine essay on how Englishmen lived with many monopoly products

Tags: identification-request, essays, thomas-paine

It was about how Englishmen lived under monopoly slate rooves, wore monopoly linens, used firegrates of monopoly iron etc.

I didn't see it the Internet Archive's copy of his complete works. So a sloppy publisher may have only attributed the essay to him. I just don't know.

Comment: The plural of 'roof' is 'roofs'.

Comment: Here are [the complete works of Thomas Paine](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/31270/pg31270.txt) as a searchable text file. I searched for `monopol` throughout the whole thing and couldn't find anything like what you describe.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Just a quick spelling correction. It is a `monopoly`. Definition: the exclusive possession or control of the supply of or trade in a commodity or service. Source: Oxford Languages.

Comment: @Silvermidnight I know that. I searched for `monopol` so that the search would pick up on words like monopoly, monopolise, monopolize, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[The Age of Reason PDF](https://klymkowskylab.colorado.edu/Readings/Thomas%20Paine%20-%20The%20Age%20of%20Reason.pdf)

This is the closest match I have to your question.

> The Age of Reason; Being an Investigation of True and Fabulous Theology is a work by English and American political activist Thomas Paine, arguing for the philosophical position of deism. It follows in the tradition of 18th-century British deism, and challenges institutionalized religion and the legitimacy of the Bible. It was published in three parts in 1794, 1795, and 1807.
>
> It was a best-seller in the United States, where it caused a short-lived deistic revival. British audiences, fearing increased political radicalism as a result of the French Revolution, received it with more hostility. The Age of Reason presents common deistic arguments; for example, it highlights what Paine saw as corruption of the Christian Church and criticizes its efforts to acquire political power. Paine advocates reason in the place of revelation, leading him to reject miracles and to view the Bible as an ordinary piece of literature, rather than a divinely-inspired text. In The Age of Reason, he promotes natural religion and argues for the existence of a creator god.
>
> Most of Paine's arguments had long been available to the educated elite, but by presenting them in an engaging and irreverent style, he made deism appealing and accessible to the masses. Originally distributed as unbound pamphlets, the book was also cheap, putting it within the reach of a large number of buyers. Fearing the spread of what it viewed as potentially-revolutionary ideas, the British government prosecuted printers and booksellers who tried to publish and distribute it. Nevertheless, Paine's work inspired and guided many free thinkers.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Age_of_Reason

*The Age of Reason* mentions very few monopolies, but upon searching for the word 'monopoly' I came upon a very fancy paragraph:

> All national institutions of churches, whether Jewish, Christian, or
> Turkish, appear to me no other than human inventions set up to terrify
> and enslave mankind, and **monopolize** power and profit.
> I do not mean by this declaration to condemn those who believe otherwise; they have the same right to their belief as I have to mine. But it is
> necessary to the happiness of man, that he be mentally faithful to himself. Infidelity does not consist in believing, or in disbelieving; it consists
> in professing to believe what he does not believe.